# How to manage password in GNOME keyring

Tags: linux, passwords, gnome, gnome-keyring

Using GNOME 3.36.

I'd like to store some passwords in a way which is scriptable but at the same time whenever any process tries to access one of these passwords, I see a confirmation dialog and have to enter a master password.

I'm trying to understand if GNOME's keyring can be used for this. So far I've found the only non-GUI way to interact with GNOME keyring - via `secret-tool`. But it seems `secret-tool` only stores/reads passwords from GNOME's "Login" keyring which is automatically unlocked after a successful login. There doesn't seem to be a way to interact with another keyring? That would mean that any application running in the background while I'm logged-in can access my passwords if it knows required key-value pairs?

It's also unclear how locking/unlocking of a keyring works. Let's say I create a new keyring, lock it and uncheck the "Unlock after login" option. Will it stay unlocked after I unlock it the first time? Looks like this is how it works, but I'd like it to automatically lock again.

Am I missing something with `secret-tool` and GNOME keyring here? If not, are there any alternatives? I'd like to stick to DE's default application suite as much as possible.